# Django form field, previous value

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there a way to get form fields rendered value when form submitted in django.

I may render form A field with value 1,
User changes the A field value to 2 and submits.
Form validation fails and I render A field with value 2 again.
User changes the value of A field to 3 and submit.

I want to see that value is 3 and previous value is 2.

Comment: you can use session for storing the previous values

Comment: I checked changed_data property , but this only checks against initial value, session store seems to be the only solution. Thanks.